# Remove analog clock from home screen

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, home-screen, clock

So I've just got a Nexus 4 (hooray for me!) and I don't know how I did it, but I've somehow got an analog clock perched over my Google search bar. I don't want it there.

It doesn't appear to be a widget - I can't just hold and drag it and remove it, and it's constant across each page.

How do I remove it / how did I put it there??

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Have you checked that it's not a Live Wallpaper? Try choosing a different wallpaper and see if the clock is gone.

Comment: Yeah I've just got a standard wallpaper selected...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to **settings**-->**apps**-->clear **data**& **cache** of launcher(I think it is  trebuchet ).

Comment: Thanks! That sorted it. Any idea why/how it got there in the first place?

Comment: May be it was a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen to me before and a reboot was enough to fix it.